# How do I start Java app or communicate with existing Java process on specific file extension opening?

Tags: java, windows, file, javafx

This occurs with many applications, for example Microsoft Word. If I click on a word file (.doc). Microsoft Word will start or communicate with an already running process.

How do I implement this with Java? Of course with my own file extension.

A file with the custom extension would just be a json/xml text document. But obviously the custom extension part is needed so windows knows what to open it with.

Eventually it would open a new screen/page in an javaFX application.

I am not sure what to call this, and I am having trouble finding examples because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involves setting file associations in the OS your java application is running in.

Oracle provides a tutorial (pretty old at this point, it mentions it was written for 8) which is about [creating self-contained application packages which bundle the code and runtime together](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/index.html). This has a section on [Using File Associations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/fileassociation.html).

When creating your bundle, you can set file associations which the installer will setup in the OS.

```
<fx:info title="File Association Demo"
         vendor="MySamples"
         description="A Demo of File Associations for Java Packager"
         category="Demos"
         license="3 Clause BSD">
    <fx:association extension="js" mimetype="text/javascript" description="JavaScript Source"/>
    <fx:association extension="groovy" mimetype="text/x-groovy" description="Groovy Source"/>
</fx:info>
```